# Assigning a Spinbutton to a textbox

Tags: excel, vba

i have a userform textbox i would like to associate with a spin button. when i insert the product ID Number i would like the spin button to be able to move up and down the column and change the value of the textbox accordingly. i tried to do this with a loop, but for some reason when the criteria for the loop is met it does not perform my if then statement. i was wondering if perhaps if anyone can provide any light on this issue. Below is my code for facilitated viewing.

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()


Dim R As Integer

Let Lastrow = Worksheets("Petrobras").Cells(Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Row


For R = 2 To Lastrow

OPPID = Worksheets("Petrobras").Cells(R, 22).Value

If TXTOpp_Num_Pbras.Value = OPPID Then
    Worksheets("Petrobras").Cells(R, 22).Offset(-1, 0).Value
    TXTOpp_Num_Pbras.Value = ActiveCell.Value



End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using a `Sub SpinButton1_Change()` and make the TextBox value equal to the SpinButton value`

Answer (score 0):

This has two textboxes and one spin button. You enter an ID in the first box, it gets a row number. The spin changes the column within that row, then sends the value of the cell to a second textbox.

```
Option Explicit

Public rownum As Long
Public colnum As Long

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
    Dim text2val As String
    If Not colnum = 1 Then
        colnum = colnum - 1
    End If
    text2val = ActiveSheet.Cells(rownum, colnum).Value 'Change ActiveSheet to the real sheet name

    Me.Controls("TextBox2").Value = text2val
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
    Dim text2val As String
    colnum = colnum + 1

    text2val = ActiveSheet.Cells(rownum, colnum).Value 'Change ActiveSheet to the real sheet name
    If Not text2val = "" Then
        Me.Controls("TextBox2").Value = text2val
    Else
        Me.Controls("TextBox2").Value = "No More Data"
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim val As String
    val = "ID" & Me.Controls("TextBox1").Value 'Concatenating ID because my Column labels have 1, 2, 3, 4
    If Not val = "" Then
        rownum = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(val).Row 'Change ActiveSheet to the real sheet name
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]